# Left join two tables while using NOT IN condition

Tags: mysql

I am trying to left join 2 tables while using the MySQL "NOT IN" condition. The problem I am having is that, if left join is null, meaning there are no entry to left join, the MySQL NOT IN operator does not work well.

Here is an example.

```
SELECT PLAYERS.*,
TYPES.GUEST_ID

FROM PLAYERS
LEFT JOIN TYPES ON TYPES.GUEST_ID = PLAYERS.GUEST_ID
WHERE PLAYERS.ID = '1' AND TYPES.GUEST_ID NOT IN('1', '2')
```

Since there are currently no matched rows in TYPES table. The NOT IN operator does not work. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IS NULL`:

```
SELECT PLAYERS.*, TYPES.GUEST_ID
FROM PLAYERS
  LEFT JOIN TYPES ON TYPES.GUEST_ID = PLAYERS.GUEST_ID
WHERE TYPES.GUEST_ID NOT IN('1', '2') OR TYPES.GUEST_ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the `on` clause

```
SELECT PLAYERS.*,
TYPES.GUEST_ID
FROM PLAYERS
LEFT JOIN TYPES ON TYPES.GUEST_ID = PLAYERS.GUEST_ID
               AND TYPES.GUEST_ID NOT IN(1, 2)
```

Comment: Thank for your response. this works too but the first solution is better for my situation.